# Designing @1x in XD(vector software) is the same as designing @3x in Photoshop (raster software)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resolution, dpi, adobe-xd

Hello I'm UI/UX designer so pixels and dpi is regular stuff for me so before few times ago I was used to designing in @3x in Photoshop (1080*1920) with dpi of 326 since designing @1x in Photoshop is quite bad because of it's raster preview nature. But nowadays people moving to vector designing tool like Sketch and XD so here my question comes.

In Adobe XD you don't have to design @3x at all since it is vector based you design @1x (360*640 points) which is density independent. From now I design @1x and export it @3x so results are same but my question is designing @1x is good? I mean my final result will be as clear as my old PS designs or it'll get blurred? Since I don't have any idea of how XD exports assets.

Edit : I'm not asking like i have vector and i'm exporting it to 200% in such case the result won't change since vector can scaled to any size but the thing i'm talking is that in XD i make a whole composition of many objects shapes and styles and when it'll scaled to 300% will styles and gradients and shadows united will give me same clear look in device like i design @3x in photoshop? Thanks :)

Comment: I would suggest you create a quick test mockup of something similar to what you normally do and test for your own environment. Even with vector software, if you are exporting/saving to a raster format it can often be best to work "at size" as opposed to enlarging upon export.

Comment: @Scott thanks for comment, i tested it in my phone and i thought that Photoshop version was quite sharp but since after app being developed preview doesn't remain exact same as it was designed in PS that's why i'm asking how does relativity of dpi and different resolution works? thanks :)